# Is TextBox behavior correct

Tags: c#, silverlight

*Why TextBox is using **e.Handled = true** in order to prevent specific characters from being typed.

**Don't we have a better way?

Isn't this a wrong design?**

Currently I want to not receive **KeyDown** event if specific **TextBox** is in focus is there a good way to do this?Or I'll have to check is the **OriginalSource** the TextBox I want...*

### Edit:

As It seems that my original question is a bit confusing Let me reform it.
Lets suppose we have a Canvas and textbox as a child of canvas.
I registered for keyDown event of canvas to do something very interesting there.
I don't want to receive keydown events when user is typing in textBox though.
Is there a way to do this without involving e.OriginalSource?

Comment: What is your question ? Don't use the keydown for that specific textbox

Comment: e.Handled = true is the best way for doing this.

Comment: Suppose you have Canvas and TextBox as Its child.I'm registering of KeyDown of canvas in order to do something, but if I typed in TextBox I don't wan't to receive this KeyDown.Naturally setting e.Handled to true will prevent event from bubbling , but in TextBox case we will have an incorrect behavior.

Comment: And finally a disadvantage to the event bubbling in WPF that everyone seemed so giddy about initially. Seems like you've created an unsolvable problem to me. You already know the solution, you just don't want to use it because it seems "inelegant".

Comment: And finally someone who understood me.I did a bit research but no way I can do this.I thought textbox might call Addhandler of frameworkelement internally , but this was not the case as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to prevent *any* input you can (in fact, *should*) also set [`ReadOnly = true`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983585%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) instead of listening to the `KeyDown` event.

If you want to *selectively* prevent key strokes, listening to `KeyDown` and setting `e.Handled` is the only way.

However, selectively preventing keystrokes is *bad* for usability; don’t do it. Instead, use the [`Validating` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating.aspx) of the text box control to validate the user input.

Comment: And if I want to register for keydown of textbox parent, but I don't want to get event if it is that specific textBox?

Comment: @Sonosar Well in that case simply *don’t* set the `e.Handled` property.

Comment: are you sure u understand what I'm talking about?Not setting e.Handled  will result in actually getting keydown event in Parent.Why textbox care that e.Handled is true?

Comment: @Sonosar “are you sure u understand what I'm talking about?” – no. I do now, after reading your comment under the question. To be honest, I don’t have a good answer to that question. I suggest editing your question and including that comment (in fact, you can replace the entire question) so it’s more visible.

Comment: I'm really sorry for as I was not able to ask my question correctly will update my original question in a minute.Thanks for your replay though.